# Rails: MiniMagick can't generate an image with single quotation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick

I have tried to develop a sentence in default image by `gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'`. The case of a single sentence is not any problem but the one of any sentences including a single quotation, the following error occurs.

> mogrify -font -fill #fff -gravity center -pointsize 24 -draw text 0,30
>
> mogrify: unable to read font `' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/964

```
module SetupOgbImage
    def build(text)
        text = prepare_text(text)
        img = MiniMagick::Image.open(Settings.ogb.base_image_path)
        img.combine_options do |config|
        config.font Settings.ogb.font_path
        config.fill Settings.ogb.color
        config.gravity Settings.ogb.gravity
        config.pointsize Settings.ogb.font_size
        config.draw "text #{Settings.ogb.text_position} '#{text}'"
        end
        img
    end

    def prepare_text(text)
        text.scan(/.{1,#{Settings.ogb.indention_count}}/)[0...Settings.ogb.row_limit].join("\n")
    end
end
```

Comment: try adding escape character for that single quotation to skip execution of that quote

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but I can't.